# Serialize extended class to JSON in Scala with Play Framework serializer

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

I would like to serialize an extended class in scala and
i have some test code..

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._
import play.api.libs.json.Json

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class JsonSerializerTest extends Specification {

  class A(val s1: String)
  case class B(s2: String) extends A("a")

  "Application" should {
    "serialize class to JSON" in {
      implicit val bWrites = Json.writes[B]
      implicit val bReads = Json.reads[B]

      val bClass = B("b")
      println(bClass.s1 + " " + bClass.s2)

      val serialized = Json.toJson[B](bClass)

      val s1 = (serialized \ "s1").asOpt[String]

      s1 should beSome[String]

    }
  }
}
```

In this case test print:

```
a b
Application should

'None' is not Some
java.lang.Exception: 'None' is not Some
```

It means that s1 field from parent class were not serialized.

The solution

```
class A(val s1: String)
case class B(override val s1: String, s2: String) extends A(s1)
```

mostly unacceptable because in real application classes have a lot of fields and specifying them explicitly every time when i extend class complicates the code.

Is there any other solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manually create the json serializers (described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators)

the problem with your version is that `Json.writes` and `Json.reads` are macros that are looking specifically at the constructor of the `case class`, and building the serializer from that (so superclass arguments aren't captured). you could copy and roll your own version of the macro: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d6c2673d91d85fd37de424951ee5ad9f4f4cce98/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala

lastly, you can make a function that takes the result of `Json.writes` and `Json.reads`, and adds on the shared fields you want. something like:

```
object A {
  def writesSubclass[T](writer: Writes[T]): Writes[T] = new Writes[T] {
    def writes(t: T) = Json.obj("s1" -> t.s1) ++ writer.writes(t).as[JsObject]
  }
}

implicit val bWrites = A.writesSubclass(Json.writes[B])
```

depending on how often your `A` gets extended, this might be your best bet.